# Fetching big array in javascript - memory and browser performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, memory-leaks

I have an object like this:

```
    {
  "ROADONE": {
    "name": "VIA LEOPOLDO GALEOTTI",
    "rClass": "Strada Comunale",
    "id": 3433454,
    "roadElements": {
      "ELEMENTONE": {
        "type": "di tronco carreggiata",
        "id": 23323223,
        "composition": "carreggiata unica"
      }
    }
  },
  "ROADTWO": {
    "name": "STRADA SENZA NOME",
    "rClass": "Strada Comunale",
    "id": 34534335,
    "roadElements": {
      "ELEMENTONE": {
        "type": "di tronco carreggiata",
        "id": "RT04801727421ES",
        "composition": "carreggiata unica"
      },
      "ELEMENTTWO": {
        "type": "di tronco carreggiata",
        "id": "RT04801727420ES",
        "composition": "carreggiata unica"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Each ROAD Object has one field called roadElements.

In roadElements there are more objects with some fields.

In my object I have approximatly 5000 elements ROADONE,ROADTWO...ecc.ecc.

For each of them there are in roadElements field approximately ten elements.

I have to scan all the object ROADONE,ROADTWO...ecc.ecc. and for each get data in roadElements list.

Actually I do this with:

```
for (var road in myObjectroad.roadElements) {
    var name = road.name;
    var roadelements = road.roadElements;

    for (var roadElKey in road.roadElements) {
        var element = road.roadElements[roadElKey];
        var elementType = element.type;
    }
}
```

This code is more expensive for browser memory, my notebook cpu goes to 90% of usages. And it requires more than 2 minutes the fetch process.

What's the best way to fetch this data in javascript?

How can I do efficiently?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you really need all that data at once?

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Can you do the parsing on the server or store the data in sql to make it easier to query?

Comment: Data comes in json format from a web service. I can't store it in sql

Comment: Could you do a server side proxy to call the service?

Comment: Yes there is a datasupplier service that query the data layer and return the results to the client